# Find most common lotto numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For each lotto game, there is six numbers drawn in excel columns E-J. My target is to list and sort most frequent numbers drawn in rage of E2:J27. How is that possible using formula? I've tried many formulas and MODE method doesn't working.
I've tried:

```
=MODE(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($E$2:$J$27,D$30:D30,0)),$E$2:$J$27))
```

or

```
=IFERROR(MODE(IF(COUNTIF(D$30:D30,$E$2:$J$27)={0},$E$2:$J$27)),"")
```

End result should look like:

| Number | Draws |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 14 |
| 24 | 17 |

[image]

Comment: You give an expected end result without data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this for example:

```
=LET(flatten, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:F27),,";"), 
 numUq, UNIQUE(flatten), matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq),
 SORT(HSTACK(numUq, DROP(FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches)),-1)),2,-1)
)
```

A second approach using `COUNTIF` is the following:

```
=LET(rng, A1:F27, counts, COUNTIF(rng,UNIQUE(rng)), 
  flattenNums, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,rng),,";"),
  flattenCnts, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,counts),,";"),
  SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(flattenNums, flattenCnts)),2,-1)
)
```

**Note**: See note at the end,  both solutions can be simplified replacing `TEXTSPLIT` (O365 version 2022) with `TOCOL` (O365 2021 version). If for your excel version `HSTACK` is not available (O365 2022 version), you can use `CHOOSE` instead ([here](https://exceljet.net/formula/combine-ranges-with-choose) is explained how).

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: Highlighted number `6` (highest number of draws [`8`]) and `45` (`4`) for testing purpose of my sample (generated using `ROUND(49*RAND(),0)`).

## Explanation

### First Solution

Using `LET` for easy reading and composition. We define the following variables. We flatten the input to be able to obtain unique Lotto numbers in the range:

```
flatten, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:F27),,";")
```

Then the unique numbers:

```
numUq, UNIQUE(flatten)
```

Then the matches we have based on unique numbers:

```
matches, XMATCH(flatten,numUq)
```

With the `matches` we can calculate the frequency (we cannot use `COUNTIF` because it expects as input argument a range and we have an array).

Now we are ready to calculate the frequency via `FREQUENCY` of the matches found:

```
FREQUENCY(matches, UNIQUE(matches))
```

We use `DROP` to remove the last row of the result. It represents the last bins (number greater than the highest count, which out of our range numbers, so we don't need it).

Finally `HSTACK` to combine all the information and to `SORT` by descending draws.

### Second Solution

Simpler, but I found it latter. I realized we can use `COUNTIF` first (using a range, and flatten it latter), for both numbers and counts. Repeated numbers will appear more than once with the same count, so we just need to remove such rows via `UNIQUE`.

**Notes**:

- For some of the functions used here (`TEXTSPLIT`, `DROP`, `HSTACK`, etc.). Please check [Function availability](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188) for your Excel version or [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-365-new-functions.htm) organized by version.
- As @Max pointed out in the comment. Flatten a range can be simplified via `TOCOL` so expressions like this: `TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,rng),,";")` can be simplified as follow: `TOCOL(rng)`.

Comment: There’s a range of new formulas in O365 worth investigating, that include flattening.  TOROW(), TOCOL(), WRAPROWS(), WRAPCOLS().

Comment: @IntoTheDeep it looks you are using the exact same formula, but for some reason Excel thinks there is an error. Try to calculate partial results trying to identify where would be the problem. Since I am not getting the error I am not able to reproduce it. Maybe some extra invisible character, I don't know. It doesn't seem an excel version incompatibility, but rather a syntax error on your end. I just copied and pasted again my formula and it works. You need to troubleshot your special situation.

Comment: @DavidLeal Please, mark that this answer is for Excel 2021 only. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal Both formulas are broken. Can you please check

Comment: @IntoTheDeep I checked again the solution in my answer and it works. I added some notes about the version, but if the question doesn't require a specific version it is assumed the latest one. It is at question level where you can add tags specifying the version, the answer doesn't have tags, it should conform with the question version requirements (and it was not specified). I understand all the mess with the versions, that is why I prefer Google Spreadsheet. It is Microsoft policy. Here a [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih0QJy_VBMysSZtkE?e=JDgS2o) to my file, so you can check it works: